# How do I count items in an array that have a specific attribute value?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

In my application, I have an array named `@apps` which is loaded by ActiveRecord with a record containing the app's name, environment, etc.

I am currently using `@apps.count` to get the number of apps in the array, but I am having trouble counting the number of applications in the array where the `environment = 0`.

I tried `@apps.count(0)` but that didn't work since there are multiple fields for each record.

I also tried something like `@apps.count{ |environment| environment = 0}` but nothing happened.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Just use `select` to narrow down to what you want:

```
@apps.select {|a| a.environment == 0}.count
```

However, if this is based on ActiveRecord, you'd be better off just making your initial query limit it unless of course you need all of the records and are just filtering them in different ways for different purposes.

I'll assume your model is call `App` since you are putting them in `@apps`:

```
App.where(environment: 0).count
```

Comment: I am going with the first solution because i need all of the records.

Comment: Depending on the number of records, it can be faster to ask the DBM to count the records, then iterating one record at a time, than it is to ask for all records, then count and iterate over them in Ruby. The DBM is optimized for handing a `count` and then iterating row-by-row. Dumping an entire table at once will beat up your DB, the DB host, the network, the host your code runs on, and your Rails server and app.

Answer (score 5):

You have the variable wrong. Also, you have assignment instead of comparison.

```
 @apps.count{|app| app.environment == 0}
```

or

```
 @apps.count{|app| app.environment.zero?}
```

Comment: This seems to always return `@apps.count` whether its `true` or `false`. For example, `@apps.count{|app| false} == @apps.count{|app| true}`

Answer (score 2):

I would use `reduce` OR `each_with_object` here:

[reduce docs](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce):

```
@apps.reduce(Hash.new(0)) do |counts, app| 
  counts[app.environment] += 1
  counts
end
```

[each_with_object docs](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object):

```
@apps.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) do |app, counts| 
  counts[app.environment] += 1
end
```

If you are able to query, use sql

`App.group(:environment).count` will return a hash with keys as environment and values as the count.